# Fake Htaccess Url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to "fake" rewrite the url.

For example, when the user access: `http://website.com/PAGE.html`, it shows the `http://website.php/handle.php?page=PAGE`, but the url still remains `website.com/PAGE.html` ( mention: `PAGE.html` does not exists on the server, `PAGE` can be replaced with any string )

Only for the `.html` extensions I want this fake redirect.
How to do ?

I tried with :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*).html /handler.php?key=$1 [L]
```

But no result.

Comment: rules don't need a leading `/`, since all urls have to have one. `^(.*).html$` would work much better.

Comment: Thanks man! Is working now !

Comment: It's not really that rules "don't need a slash, since all urls have to have one.", it's because the "directory prefix" is removed from the URL-path when matching the pattern in .htaccess files.